# How can I trigger the default button on a form without clicking it (winforms)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two text boxes. one for login id and another is for password. and there is one button (submit). I need an event that takes the values of login id and password. I.e, without clicking the mouse I need to invoke this event(just by hitting 'enter' on keyboard). can anybody help me!

thanx in advance.
srini.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the click event and filtering for the "enter" key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon P Stevens gave you the most adequate answer.

I would just add that you also have the possibility to set a form's **CancelButton** on which a click event would be triggered when you press the escape **ESC** key.

Quick summary

**Enter** --> **AcceptButton**

**Esc**   --> **CancelButton**

Comment: thanx dude.glad to see these kind of responses...very gud site!

Answer (score 18):

Set the button to be the accept button on the form. You can do this by setting the forms "AcceptButton" property to be the button you want to trigger. This will make an enter key press trigger the button.

Comment: can u help me where shud i set this.
im new to c#,don be hesitated if im asking a naive one!!!

Comment: It's a property on the form. Select your form. Hit F4. Find the "AcceptButton" property, change it to the button you want to be the default button. The button should be highlighted slightly (with a blue border on windows XP) to indicate it is the default button.

Comment: As per my knowledge..using the "AcceptButton", the form will close even if no username & password is entered and you show a message that na error has occurred.
You will have to add some code to form closing even to NOT close the form incase error has occured.

Comment: Setting the button as the AcceptButton won't close the form. All it will do is cause the buttons click event to be triggered when you press enter.

Answer (score 2):

use

buttonName.**PerformClick()**;

Comment: Worked! and very simple

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the button to be the default you can hook both TextBoxes KeyPress events to same handler then check if Enter was pressed using KeyEventArgs.KeyCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to navigate the form without the mouse, you'll want to make sure your tab stops are set correctly.  I would set Login Id as the first, password as the second, and your submit button as the third.  Then the user can navigate easily among them.  IIRC, the default behavior of buttons is to fire off the On_Click event if the Enter key is pressed while the button has focus.

Comment: dude thats ok but when i hit enter the action shud invoke imean to say
not by focusing on submit and when i hit enter the action shud invoke

Comment: and i would like to ask u ppl waht is the e.KeyChar eqivalent to the enter button