# How to capture Enter Button Pressed Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, authentication

The image below shows a part of my Login form . The program works fine and I am able to login when I press the Enter Button. But I want to Login when I press My Enter Button (Return Button) on my Keyboard. How can I do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the properties of the form set the `Accept button property`to the Enter button which will gives your desired.

Comment: Thank you it helped me as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
Me.AcceptButton = YourButton
YourButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
```

pressing Return (on your Keyboard) will cause this Button_Click event to fire.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the Form's [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to your Enter-Button.
Additionally you could set it's CancelButton to your Clear-Button. That calls the clear-function to be triggered when user presses Esc-Key.

By the way, this was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097853/how-can-i-trigger-the-default-button-on-a-form-without-clicking-it-winforms).

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub frmcalculator_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Call btnequals_Click(sender, e)
        End If
```